# How could I change this hardcoded data to data from my database?

Tags: android

I would like to change it by getting the data from the database .

```
public void initList(){
    product = new String[]{"apple","apricot","banana","orange","nuts","pears","pineapple","watermelon"};
    listProducts = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(product));
    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_item,R.id.txtitem, listProducts);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For lists that come from the database, you should use a `CursorAdapter`

```
    public void initList() {
        String[] from = new String[] { productColName };
        int[] to = new int[] { R.id.txtitem };
        Cursor cursor = db.query(.....);
        CursorAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(context, R.layout.list_item, cursor, from, to, 0);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
```

This is an easy way to handle database data for a list item with all `TextViews`.  If you have more complex data, such as for images etc. you should create a `CursorAdapter` subclass and override `newView()` and `bindView()`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use SQLite db, which is commonly used in android apps. You can insert and retrieve the data using SQLite queries.

For your example: you can create a table consisting the names of the fruits.
You can query your database to get all the fruits and populate the list (by adding the retrieved results in to the list) and use it as you are using it now to inflate the listView.

You can use the following tutorial to know about how to create a table, insert/update an entry and retrieve data from the table.
[SQLite setup and sample queries](http://www.androidauthority.com/use-sqlite-store-data-app-599743/)